# iPhone mapKit annotation for Current Location

Tags: iphone, objective-c, annotations, mapkit

Im currently strugglung with annotations. how can i prevent the AnnotationLable for the blue GPS-point. ([Here is an Image](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/38a3a70091.png))

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(MKAnnotation *) annotation{


 if (annotation == mapView.userLocation) { 
  return nil;
 }
```

the function above isnt working, and i realized that i can't compare two coordinates.

Any hint is welcome. Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing an annotation to a location in your if.

Are you trying to supress the current location annotation for a reason? It is common UI with map kit and the consistency helps users understand the blue dot.

Comment: so i shouldn't deactivate it ?!

Comment: I don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish maybe you can share a bit more. The "current location" label only appears if a user taps it and it can be helpful when someone isn't sure what the flashing blue dot is. A veteran user is going to know but someone who is new can find it helpful.

Comment: He's comparing an MKAnnotation to MKUserLocation, which implements the MKAnnotation protocol.